# A forma correta de se contar uma array em PHP

Tags: php, array, count

Gostaria de tirar uma dúvida, tenho um script aonde conto o total de arquivos de um diretório e comparo com os arquivos do banco, está tudo funcionando.

**A minha dúvida é a seguinte:** Quando eu coloco um código para ser exibido os erros, **exibe um erro**, porém está funcionando, eu simplesmente ignoro e tiro a exibição do erro? ou estou utilizando o `count` errado?

> *Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /exemplo.php on line 69*

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); // Esse é o código que força mostrar o erro


 foreach($files as $file){
    if(!in_array($file, $images)){

      echo "Cerca de <b>" .count($file). "</b> arquivo(s) que não estão no banco de dados <p>"; //Ele diz que tem erro nessa linha

      echo "Nomes dos arquivos: <b>" . $file . "</b><br>"; 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ele dá um aviso, não erro, pois você está passando um valor que não é um array em algum caso. Tente colocar um `is_array($file)` antes de usar o `count()`.

Comment: `is_array($file)` não retornou nada... então, como é um aviso, "não tem problema"

Comment: O `is_array` é para verificar se é um array só, aí você imprime o `count`

Comment: Obrigado @rbz, você já respondeu a minha dúvida.

Answer (score 0):

no caso você ta fazendo o count errado, você ta contando o índice $file e não o array $files

tente:

```
count($files)
```

Comment: Olá, eu diria que não, está correto... mas mesmo assim, obrigado por tentar ajudar.

Comment: chegou a testar?

Comment: Sim, esse post era mais uma "dúvida",  os códigos estão corretos.

Comment: ata, ok. só estava respondendo a essa pergunta:" ou estou utilizando o count errado?" onde disse que sim, estava pq tava contando índice e não o array, mas ok.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo o que deu pra entender, a variável **$file** contém o nome do arquivo. Se for isso, ela é uma variável do tipo string, por isso está acusando erro. Para que o count() funcione, a variável $file tem que ser um array ou objeto de uma classe que implemente a interface **Countable**, como a mensagem de erro está informando.

Se você usar **count($files)**, vai parar de exibir o erro, mas a lógica talvez não esteja muito correta.